# Uninstalling the karma generator does not remove the files

Tags: npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Running this command does not uninstall or remove anything:

```
npm uninstall -g generator-karma
```

In my client folder there are still files + folders related to karma:

```
node_modules
karma.conf.js
karma-e2e.conf.js
```

How can I remove those folder/files? with npm/yeoman?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the generator doesn't remove what you generated. To do that you should keep everything in version control so you can just revert the generation.